# Set empty variable from a MySQL Query to false using while read

Tags: mysql, bash

MySQL-Version:
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.31-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
Bash-Version: GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

I'm using the following code with Bash to do a MySQL query.

The value of "ssl" in the MySQL Database is empty (I check that with the condition SELECT * FROM domains WHERE ssl=')

```
while read ssl certificate_id; do

echo $ssl
echo $certificate_id

done < <(mysql -NB -utheuser -pthemysqlpass psa -e  "SELECT ssl, certificate_id FROM domains WHERE id='26';")
```

If ssl is empty in the database, the read command will ignore or skip this variable and set the value of certificate_id to ssl.

I tried a lot of variants using IFS= but it didn't work.

I want to set the value of "ssl" to "false" if "ssl" is empty.

Do you have an idea how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Bit of an out-there idea: can you join to `null`? e.g. `SELECT ... FROM ... RIGHT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT NULL as term ) WHERE ...` The idea being a right outer join will append all the values on the left (your select thus far) to the values on the right (the null). If no values are available on the left, it would give you null values for sql/sql_certificate/etc

Comment: For the above you'd also have to `SELECT ..., term` I believe

Comment: Thank you Rogue! I will test this and post an update.

Comment: Update: The value isn't NULL but it seems to be empty.
If I do a SELECT * FROM domains WHERE ssl = ''; -> One result with all the informations from id 26. But with WHERE ssl IS NULL -> No line found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I found an alternative using the IF function of MySQL:

SELECT IF(ssl = '', 'false', ssl) ssl, certificate_id FROM domains WHERE id='26';"

I have to do more tests using bash but the first tests using PHPMyAdmin gave the correct result.

Maybe it will help others!